# moving a script from 2003 to 2008 or 2012

Tags: vbscript

We have a vbscript that is supposed to move customer invoices from a home grown application into SAP. The script is currently running on a 2003 server and needs to be moved to a 2008R2 or 2012 server. I have moved all files and directories over to the new machine. I ran process explorer on the 2003 script and found that it was using 3 dll files. I have those files registered on the new system. One of those DLL files is a home grown file that goes with the home grown app. unfortunately I do not know how to script so I am not sure what the vbs script is actually doing. Does anyone know where I can look to try and figure this out?

Comment: Is there a way to log what the script is doing so I can see where it is failing? Maybe some sort of debugging?

Comment: what is the error you're getting? Keep in mind that 2003 is 32-bit whilst the other two are likely 64-bit.

Comment: @fritz what are you talking about?  Moved to 2008R2? whats that? 
You talking about SQL Server SSIS? There is NO vbscripts in SSIS, you need to convert them to .NET . In 2008 ActiveX task existed for backwards compatibility and it was deprecated.